# jacoco - aggregate aggregated reports

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm using jacoco maven plugin, and I have multiple repos each with multiple modules, I use report-aggregate in each of them to get a report of each repo. I want to create an aggregated report of all of the repos, is there an option to do that?